# Proving the closed form of a sum of hypergeometric functions ${}_{2}F_{1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the process of developing a power-series expansion for a particular product of integer-order Bessel functions, I've discovered that the series greatly simplifies provided that the following finite summation over hypergeometric functions ${}_{2}F_{1}$ on the left side sums to the simple closed form on the right:$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(m-k+1\right)^{m-k}\left(m-k+2\right)^{m+k+1}{}_{2}F_{1}\left(-k,-m-2;m-k+2;\left(\frac{m-k+1}{m-k+2}\right)^{2}\right)}{k!\left(m-k+1\right)!}\overset{?}{=}\frac{2\left(-1\right)^{m}}{m!}$$

Using Mathematica I've verified that this relation is true for all integers $m$ from 0 to 100, but I don't know how to go about proving it in general. Any suggestions?

Comment: Noting that hypergeometric functions are polynomials for negative numerator arguments, the given ${}_2F_1$ is a $k$-th order polynomial. Thus, your statement is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^m \sum_{n=0}^k (-1)^{m-k}
\frac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{k}{n}\binom{m+2}{n}}{\binom{m+n-k+1}{n}}
(m-k+1)^{m-(k+1-2n)}
(m-k+2)^{m+(k+1-2n)} = 1 \, .
$$
Maybe one can now change the evaluation order of the two finite sums to proof the equality.

Comment: The Wilf-Zeilberger method works for such identities and gives painless 'automated' proofs. Google WZ pair.